# How to get parameter values passed into a function as strings

Tags: python, string, parameters, inspect

I have a function which takes 2 parameters, I would like to get the values passed into those two parameters as string. However, the function is stored in a separate module from where it's being used and ran.

In module x we have the function:

```
def meta_filter(table, orientation):
     #code code code
```

In module y, the function is being used like this:

```
meta_filter(dataframe, left)
```

I would like to get the objects passed into the meta_filter as string.

```
'dataframe', 'left'
```

I am doing this because it will save me from writing a lot of unnecessary code.

Comment: [Why do you want this?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: i am not so clear about your question, could you elaborate little more.

Comment: I've tried to provide more info, hope it a bit clearer now.

Answer (score 0):

Use inspect to get parent frame's locals and then find that variables that point to the same objects:

```
import inspect

def meta_filter(table, orientation):
    names = [''] * 2
    frame = inspect.currentframe()
    try:
        for var, val in frame.f_back.f_locals.iteritems():
            if val is table:
                names[0] = var
            if val is orientation:
                names[1] = var

    finally:
        del frame

    print (names)

a = 10
b = 'abc'
meta_filter(a, b)
```

Output:

```
['a', 'b']
```

Comment: You have understood what I am tried to do but I've not got your code to work. Could it be because my function is stored in one module but called in another?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am misunderstanding, but do you just want the class names. If so, why not:

```
>>> class DataFrame:
...     pass
... 
>>> class Left:
...     pass
... 
>>> dataframe = DataFrame()
>>> left = Left()
>>> 
>>> def meta_filter(table, orientation):
...     return table.__class__.__name__, orientation.__class__.__name__
... 
>>> meta_filter(dataframe, left)
('DataFrame', 'Left')
```

I suspect there is a better way of doing what you are trying to do though..

EDIT:

Oh, do you actually want the variable names, maybe anton's answer is better then

Comment: Yes you are right, I am after the variable names. Apologies if my description was not clear.